# What is the difference between these two questions?

Tags: support

Why is this accepted, and upvoted
[Is James Bond explicitly described as caucasian in Ian Fleming's books?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/28623/is-james-bond-explicitly-described-as-caucasian-in-ian-flemings-books?lq=1)

And this question closed as off topic 
[Is Miss Moneypenny describe caucasian in the novels? [closed]](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/28664/is-miss-moneypenny-describe-caucasian-in-the-novels)

Answer (score 3):

In short, because the first question relates to the main character of the Bond series, posed a potentially interesting question about casting decision.  The Moneypenny question is derivative, a point that you explicitly make yourself in comments.  Essentially, you could ask the same question about any character based on any book that has been adapted as a movie.  **I don't think it would be interesting or healthy for the M&TV site to do so.**

As far as the Movie and TV community is concerned, we are not really that interested in a question about the description of the characters except in the context of the movies.  At face value a question purely about Bond's physical description in the novels would be off-topic here, and as of now the question about Bond himseld is barely holding on (with 4 close votes).  I think it survives because it poses the question about whether its suitable to cast someone with a significant physical difference from that described in the novel.

I believe the Bond question is still open because of the more general case that it addresses.  It could certainly be asked better, and I would welcome people attempting to edit it in a way that improves it.  The Moneypenny question while superficially similar is essentially either off-topic (because it is purely about a book), or duplicate (because its about race in casting decisions in Bond movies).

Comment: So basically this stems from an argument that started on new years eve... and without reading all the books I was interested in the answer.  Do you have a recommendation on how to go about getting the question answered.  There does not seem to be a books.se or bond.se ?

Comment: Make it about the movie, not the book. Like I said in the comments before: Has character x in movie y been altered at all from it's source material. Totally different than how is character x portrayed in the book?

Comment: Thank you I edited the question but it was removed, I will ask again in two days.  Again unless there is a book.se website?  Also while the Bond question was put as off topic, now, it and its answer was well received by the community.

Comment: @Mike - Literature.SE failed to make it out of beta and was closed as a site unfortunately.